# Using apply() over a list

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list with 100 vectors indexed by:

```
[[1]]
[1]
[[2]]
[1]
[[3]]
[1]
.
.
.
[[100]]
[1]
```

Each vector has 3 entries.

I would like to apply a function separately for each of the vectors. The function returns a single number for each vector so the result of the apply() would be a 100 element vector.

How can this be done using apply?

I know I can use apply for matrices by indexing 1 or 2 depending on row or column but can it also be used for lists?

Comment: I googled for "r apply lists" and the first link was the answer.

Comment: `?apply` says it's for arrays/matrices. The *See Also* section says to look at `lapply`, which also describes `sapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `sapply`:

```
l <- list(1:3, 2:4, 5:7)
sapply(l, sum)
# [1]  6  9 18
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/1320535) might help you in the future.